# fasm windows 10 без макро и библиотек

Tags: ассемблер, windows-10, fasm

каким образом можно реализовать чистый код на ассемблере, без включений библиотек и макросов на windows 10, обычный "Hello world!" через регистры, метки, понятно что функции dos уже не будет, но каким либо способом ведь это можно сделать?

Comment: `c:\fasm\EXAMPLES\PEDEMO\PEDEMO.ASM`, например, без подключения внешних файлов, без использования макросов, но с WinAPI. Без WinAPI вы в пользовательском режиме в Windows вы никакой ввод-вывод не сможете сделать.

Comment: да, это понимаю, вот именно это и хотел узнать, что если обратиться к этому API то ведь там тоже происходят какие либо действия, которые думаю так же могут представлять из себя ассемблерные команды.

Comment: Вызовы WinAPI обращаются к более низкоуровневым функциям, в самом низу идет обращение к функциям ядра, которое уже работает не в пользовательском режиме (3 кольцо), а в режиме ядра (0 кольцо). Это слишком большая тема, чтобы можно было дать простой ответ. Попробуйте почитать, например, `Аблязов Р.З. - Программирование на ассемблере на платформе х86-64`.